# Perl SOAP::WSDL accessing HTTPS Unathorized error

Tags: perl, soap, https, wsdl

I'm trying to generate a Perl library to connect to a WebService. This webservice is in an HTTPS server and my user has access to it.

I've executed wsdl2perl.pl several times, with different options, and it always fails with the message: `Unauthorized at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/SOAP/WSDL/Expat/Base.pm line 73.`
The thing is, when I don't give my user/pass as arguments, it doesn't even asks for them.

I've read [SOAP::WSDL::Manual::Cookbook] (http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL/Manual/Cookbook.pod) and done what it says about HTTPS: Crypt::SSLeay is instaleld, and both SOAP::WSDL::Transport::HTTP and SOAP::Transport::HTTP are modified.

Can you give any hint about what may be going wrong?

Comment: I am truly sorry for your kind interest but I cannot recall what I was working on back then. Looking at my logs, it seems I was ordered to connect to a Sharepoint WS to retrieve some information so now I suppose I needed NTLM auth. This project is long dead so I'm really sorry for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Can you freely access the WSDL file from your web browser?
Can someone else in your network access it without any problems?

Maybe the web server hosting the WSDL file requires Basic or some other kind of Authentication...

Answer (score 0):

If not necessary ,I don't recommend you to use perl as a web service client .As you know ,perl is a open-source language,although it do support soap protocol,but its support do not seem very standard.At first,its document is not very clear.And also ,its support sometimes is limited.At last,bug always exists here and there.

So ,if you have to use wsdl2perl,you can use komodo to step into the code to find out what happened.This is just what I used to do when using perl as a web service client.You know ,in the back of https is SSL,so ,if your SSL is based on certificate-authorized,you have to set up your cert path and the list of trusted server cert.You'd better use linux-based firefox to have a test.As I know ,you can set up firefox's cert path and firefox's trusted cert list.If firefox can communicated with your web service server succefully,then,it's time to debug your perl client.

Answer (score 0):

To debug situations with Perl and SOAP, interpose a web proxy so you can see exactly what data is being passed and what response comes back from the server. You were getting a 401 Not authorized, I expect, but there may be more detail in the server response.

Both Fiddler http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler and Charles proxy https://www.charlesproxy.com/ can do this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you quote seems to be from this line :
`die $response->message() if $response->code() ne '200';`
and in HTTP world, `Unauthorized` is clearly error code 401, which means your website asks for a username and password (most probably, some website may "hijack" this error code to cater for other conditions like a filter on the source IP).
Do you have them?

If so, you can

- after `wdsl2perl` has run, find in the created files where `set_proxy()` is called and change the URL in there to include the username and password like that : `...->set_proxy('http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.example.com/...')`
- or your in code, after instantiating the `SOAP::WSDL` object, call `service(SERVICENAME)` on it (for each service you have defined in your WSDL file), which gives you a new object, on which you call `transport()` to access the underlying transport object on which you can call `proxy()` with the URL as formatted above (yes it is `proxy()` here and `set_proxy()` above); or you call `credentials()` instead of `proxy()` and you pass 4 strings:

  1. 'HOSTNAME:PORT'
  2. the realm, as given by the webserver but I think you can put anything
  3. the username
  4. the password